# C#\HtmlAgilityPack Parse Other Then FIreBug

Tags: c#, html-parsing, firebug, html-agility-pack

im using `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse Html nodes,
im using firebug to search the node attributes which im looking for, like div with class name "ABC"
I've noticed that sometimes im getting no result for the div im looking for, i debug that and saw that the `XPATH` from firebug and from `HtmlAgilityPack` is different for the same Node:S

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/table[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/td[1]/div[1]

/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div
```

First one is firebug. nyone knows where im wrong?

Comment: Hi,  
"I've noticed that sometimes im getting no result for the div im looking for"  
What is returning no result? (Firebug, HtmlAgilityPack, ...)

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is returning null .

Comment: And can you share (if possible) the rendered HTML Document (on http://jsfiddle.net/ for example), so we can test the XPath expressions?

Comment: im not familiar with jsfiddle , i paste on pastebin.
when i press view-source-code on firefox i get this - http://pastebin.com/jJthHAF
and i get this from HAP - as documentNode.OuterHtml - 
moreover, im using firepath ,that allow to write xpath to firebug, i take the expression from there ,paste it to HAP and get 0 results sometimes:S

http://pastebin.com/ffv7XvzE

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons

1. HTML Agility Pack is not parsing the HTML correctly
2. The web page has been altered by client script after the page was loaded. When you view with Firebug, you are looking at the DOM, not the HTML source. HAP can only work the HTML source.

You will notice in the paths you have shown that (for example) there are no TBODY tags in the HAP version. TBODY is is optional in HTML markup, but still a required tag in a complete DOM. Browser HTML parsers will always add TBODY if it's missing. HAP will not. This can result in paths that work in a browser, failing in HAP

An alternative to HAP is [CsQuery](http://www.github.com/jamietre/csquery) (on [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/csquery)), which uses a standards-compliant HTML parser (actually - the same parser as Firefox). CsQuery is a C# jquery port, it works  with CSS selectors (not xpath). It should give you a DOM that matches the one the browser shows. This will not change anything if the problem is simply that javascript is altering the DOM, though.

Comment: ive noticed now that javascript changed some of the page after i load it,maybe that the problem , anyway i can get the page after the javascript ran?

Comment: Do you have any concrete "facts" related to this specific question upon which you base your 1) reason? Html Agility Pack is not the only piece of code involved.

Comment: @Simon Mourier, does HAP's parser do tag interpolation, or otherwise conform to the HTML5 parser specs? It did not last time I checked. In numerous test cases I have done, it does not return the same DOM as browsers in situations involving optional tags (and the rules for parsing invalid markup, which are extensive). As far as I know, it never claimed to be that.

Comment: @roee- you can't, using a native .NET solution. You really want a "headless browser" - something that can both parse the HTML and run the script just as a real browser would: a browser without a viewing window. None exists in complete form in .NET, your best bet may be to use the browser control, which is not especially clean or fast, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Html Agility Pack only concentrates on markup. It has no idea of how things will be rendered. Firebug I think relies on the current in-firefox-memory DOM which can be dramatically different. That's why you see elements such as TBODY that only exist in DOM, not in markup (where they are optional).

Plus you can add to that the fact that there is an infinite possible XPATH expression for a given Xml node.

Anyway, in general, the needed XPATH when doing queries using Html Agility Pack don't need the full XPATH expression that a tool would give. You just need to focus on discriminants, for example specific attributes (like the class), id, etc.... Your code will be much more resistant to changes. But it means you need to learn a bit about XPATH (this is a good starting point: [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp)). So you really want to build XPATH expression such as this:

```
//div[@class = 'ABC']
```

which will get all DIV elements with a CLASS attribute named 'ABC'.